# MySQL history show a lot of \040

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, history

When I tried to see the history of mysql - I see this

> cat ~/.mysql_history

I got this :

```
└──  cat ~/.mysql_history
_HiStOrY_V2_
exit
GRANT\040ALL\040PRIVILEGES\040ON\040*\040.\040*\040TO\040'jada'@'localhost';
FLUSH\040PRIVILEGES;
select\040User,Host\040from\040mysql.user;
exit
select\040User,Host\040from\040mysql.user;
GRANT\040ALL\040PRIVILEGES\040ON\040*\040.\040*\040TO\040'jada'@'localhost';
FLUSH\040PRIVILEGES;
select\040User,Host\040from\040mysql.user;
exit
drop\040database\app;\040
show\040databases;\040
create\040database\app;\040
exit
show\040databases;\040
use\app;\040
select\040*\040from\040users;\040
exit
use\app;\040
select\040*\040from\040users;\040
exit
select\040User,Host\040from\040mysql.user;
GRANT\040ALL\040PRIVILEGES\040ON\040*\040.\040*\040TO\040'jada'@'localhost';
FLUSH\040PRIVILEGES;
select\040User,Host\040from\040mysql.user;
exit
select\040User,Host\040from\040mysql.user;
exit
select\040*\040from\040users;
show\040databases;\040
use\app\040;\040
select\040*\040from\040users;
DELETE\040FROM\040table_name\040WHERE\040condition;
DELETE\040FROM\040users\040WHERE\040id\040=\0402;
select\040*\040from\040users;
history
show\040history;
exit
```

I saw a bunch of `\040`.

How do I see a clean history like a regular history in bash ?

I've tried on 5 VMs. Same result. All the time.

Comment: `\040` is the space character.

Comment: I don't see anything like that. What does `type cat` show?

Comment: What version of `mysql` are you running?

Comment: @Barmar I am on `Server version: 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.19.10.1`

Comment: `type cat` return 
`cat is hashed (/usr/bin/cat)`

Comment: This is a client issue, not server. But maybe they changed the format of the history file (I'm still using 5.x).

Comment: I do not think they changed the format... (so it must be a client issue), try `hash -r`   (after reading what it will do)

Comment: I tried on the Terminal and ssh shell , 2 apps show the same.

Comment: client is more than how you connect to your server.... (`hash` has not much to do with the client, only with how it behaves)

Comment: Please share more details. How is this even related to programming? To me, this looks pretty off-topic here

Comment: The file is a text file, and actually has those 4 characters for space.  It probably has 4 characters for many other characters, especially 8-bit codes.

Comment: FYI:  `\040` is the octal escape sequence for "space".  (This does not explain how to undo the seemingly unnecessary escaping.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/\\040/ /g' < .mysql_history
```

This only fixes spaces; I don't know the extent of the problem.

`\0xx` is an octal escape sequence.  `40` is the octal for `space`.

Answer (score 2):

I remember is old bug on mysql client https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68925
try to update it

Answer (score 1):

### This is a common job for [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -pe 's/\\([0-7]{1,3})/chr oct $1/eg' <.mysql_history
```

This will *resolve* octal representations (not only *spaces*).

Demo/test:

```
perl -pe 's/\\([0-7]{1,3})/chr oct $1/eg' <<<"SELECT\040\042String\042;"
SELECT "String";
```

### But this could by done under [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)

Line by line, mostly if required for one line, you could

```
echo -e "GRANT\040ALL\040PRIVILEGES\040ON\040*\040.\040*\040TO\040'jada'@'localhost';"
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'jada'@'localhost';
```

### or better, with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
printf %b\\n "GRANT\040ALL\040PRIVILEGES\040ON\040*\040.\040*\040TO\040'jada'@'localhost';"
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'jada'@'localhost';
```

Of couse, you could loop over whole file:

```
while read -r line ;do
    printf '%b\n' "$line"
done <.mysql_history
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the \040 with space character using sed command and define an alias for the same, so that you can simply call alias instead of repeating the full command:  Alias mysqlh for mysql history

```
$ alias mysqlh="cat ~/.mysql_history | sed 's/\\\040/ /g'"
$ mysqlh
_HiStOrY_V2_
exit
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'jada'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
select User,Host from mysql.user;
exit
select User,Host from mysql.user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'jada'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
select User,Host from mysql.user;
exit
drop database\app;
show databases;
create database\app;
exit
show databases;
use\app;
select * from users;
exit
use\app;
select * from users;
exit
select User,Host from mysql.user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'jada'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
select User,Host from mysql.user;
exit
select User,Host from mysql.user;
exit
select * from users;
show databases;
use\app ;
select * from users;
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 2;
select * from users;
history
show history;
exit
```